# Creating Google Maps link from form data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have address form scope like this:

```
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Address</label>
          <input name="text" ng-model="location.address">
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container>
          <label>Zip</label>
          <input name="text" ng-model="location.zip">
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container>
          <label>City</label>
          <input name="text" ng-model="location.city">
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container>
          <select ng-model="selectedCountry" pvp-country-picker="country">
            <option value="" disabled>Please select your country</option>
          </select>
        </md-input-container>
```

And I want first off, find latitude and longitude alias and show me on the Google maps.

How can I do it?

Comment: So just to clarify, you want to take the input from the form and build a google maps url to send them to?

Comment: @GarrettWills Yes, it is.